# DRF SerializerMethodField method only running when serializer variable opened in debugger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My `SerializerMethodField` method is only printing `HERE` when I have a breakpoint at the `return` in the `get` method, and open the `serializer` variable after it has triggered OR when `serializer.data` is called (in which case it prints the expected data, but `validated_data` is still empty).

View:

```py
class EventAddPeople(generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = EventAddPeopleSerializer_Read

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = EventAddPeopleSerializer_Read(data=request.GET)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        print(serializer.validated_data)
        return HttpResponse(serializer.validated_data)
```

Serializer:

```py
class EventAddPeopleSerializer_Read(serializers.Serializer):
    event_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_event_id')
    person_ids = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_event_id(self, obj):
        print("HERE")
        return "TEST00"

    def get_person_ids(self, obj):
        print("HERE")
        return "TEST00"

    class Meta:
        fields = ('event_id', 'person_ids')
```

[image: HTTP Request]

Comment: Where are you expecting that `print` statement to show up?  In general, you need to use django's loggers to print something out to the log.

Comment: It was just for testing, I expect it to print to the terminal. But why is `validated_data` empty @RishiG?

Comment: @W.Reyna Are you sending data to the API using HTTP POST method?

Comment: @JPG No, using GET. I think I will start a fresh project with just this to test.

Comment: @W.Reyna Checkout the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your get method is not called (may be).

check by just printing('anything') in your get method

check [Methos](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) for genericApiViews

Thanks

Comment: No, I have verified that the method works with a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, **`request.data`** is applicable for ***non-GET requests***. You are not supposed to send data in the payload section with HTTP GET. If you want to send data with GET method, pass it through ***URL query parameters***
So, the url will become, `/api/my/end-point/?event_id=1&person_ids=3`
and you need to pass this query param to serializer as,

```
serializer = EventAddPeopleSerializer_Read(data=request.GET)
```

---

Second thing, you've missed to add the **`Meta class`** in the serializer

```
class EventAddPeopleSerializer_Read(serializers.Serializer):
    # other code
    class Meta:
        fields = ('event_id', 'person_ids')
```

Comment: Don't think so, `print(serializer.validated_data)` still only prints `OrderedDict()`. Also GET response is blank.

Comment: Something interesting happened, I did `serializer.data`, and it gave me an error about `get_person_ids` not existing. Fixed it, and `serializer.data` gave me the correct stuff (`TEST00`). But `validated_data` is still blank.

Comment: I forgot about that. I have updated my code as well to use `post` and keep `request.data`. Though the issue still persists

Comment: `SerializerMethodField`  method field will return data only with **`HTTP GET`** method

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I have once again updated my code, please take a look. I tried querying like this: `GET /endpoint/?event_id=1&person_ids=1` but it's still blank

Comment: What is the result of **`print(request.GET)`** ?

Comment: `<QueryDict: {'event_id': ['1'], 'person_ids': ['1']}>`

Comment: What is the output of **`print(serializer.data)`**?

Comment: `{'event_id': 'TEST00', 'person_ids': 'TEST00'}`